Not loading dictionary in lazy-module for ngx-translate in Angular 16+
After migrationg on Angular 16+ not loading dictionaries in lazy-modules.  I tried everything I found in the answers on StackOverflow. I wrote simple application, which demonstrate thia problem. The child module (chills.module) does not retain the loader that is defined in сreateChillsLoader.
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateLoader, TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {RouterLink, RouterModule, RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router';
import {HttpClient, provideHttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {routes} from './app.routes';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http,
    './assets/i18n/app/main.', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, TranslateModule.forRoot({
      defaultLanguage: 'en',
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
    extend: true
    }
  ), RouterOutlet, RouterLink, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [provideHttpClient()]
})
export class AppModule {

}

app.routes.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'chills',
    loadChildren: () => import('../app/modules/chills/chills.module').then(m => m.ChillsModule)
  },
];

chills.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {Route, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {ChillsviewComponent} from './chillsview/chillsview.component';

export function createChillsLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/app/chills.');
}

const routes: Route[] = [
  {path: '', component: ChillsviewComponent},
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ChillsviewComponent],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes), CommonModule, TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateModule,
        useFactory: createChillsLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },

      extend: true,
      useDefaultLang: true,
      defaultLanguage: 'en'
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class ChillsModule { }

chillsview.component.html
<p>{{ 'chills' | translate }}</p>

package.json
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/common": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.2.0",
  "@angular/router": "^18.2.0",
  "@ngx-translate/core": "15.0.0",
  "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "8.0.0",
  "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
  "tslib": "^2.3.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.14.10"
},

[Module factory function invoke on loading "chills" module] (https://i.sstatic.net/OOGj8p18.png)
but was loaded "main" dictionary
Maybe someone has encountered this situation?
